# Passing URL as string -- everything after '&' gets lost

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC application that makes an API call in an onclick event

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="@Model.MyApiCall"></a>
```

@Model.MyApiCall is a string that looks something like this:

```
window.location = 'http://localhost/myPath?myImagePath=http://myimagepath&width=360&category=2'
```

This successfully calls my API. So far so good.
However, for some reason everything after & is getting cut off from myImagePath. So instead of myImagePath equaling what was sent from my click, I'm only getting this:

```
http://myimagepath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand (&) is a special character and needs to be encoded to be properly parsed by the browser.  You'll need to break up your query string and actual path into separate strings.  Something like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="@(Model.MyApiCallPath +
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Model.MyApiCallQueryString))"></a>
```

Your final js will look something like:

```
window.location = 'http://localhost/myPath?myImagePath=http%3A%2F%2Fmyimagepath%26width%3D360%26category%3D2';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode your query string parameter. You can do it in javascript:

```
window.location = 'http://localhost/myPath?myImagePath=' + encodeURIComponent('http://myimagepath') + '&width=360&category=2'
```

using `encodeURIComponent`.

You can also do it inside your MVC controller using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` only on the `http://myimagepath` part of your `Model.MyApiCall`.

[Edit]

If your `myImagePath` parameter is the entire `http://myimagepath&width=360&category=2` string then of course Steve Danner is right and you should follow his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a url as a url parameter. Since the url in question contains special characters, you need to escape/encode the uri components.

Since you're using ASP.Net, you should wrap the string with:

```
window.location = Uri.EscapeUriString('http://localhost/myPathmyImagePath=http://myimagepath&width=360&category=2')
```